# Possible to restore MSSQL Backup to different database name using PHP PDO?

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, pdo

Is it possible to restore MSSQL Express Backup file to a **different** database name on another server running MSSQL Server using only PHP PDO and FTP access?

Comment: Why would you use PHP, PDO or FTP access to restore the database? Just restore it via MSSQL

Comment: I only have FTP and PHP access

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without a copy of the database first.  Use the detach, copy, reattach method.

I suggest the following which should all be doable with PHP PDO.  But first you have to detach, copy and reattach with the new name.

1. Make a backup, with TSQL from php, just to be safe.
2. Detach the database you want to copy, with TSQL from php. (this will take it offline)
3. Copy the files from the original database over to new names.  Use php functions to do the copy.
4. Reattach the original, with TSQL from php
5. Attach the copy with a new name, with TSQL from php.

Be sure to practice this somewhere first so that you know it will work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

YES IT IS POSSIBLE BUT U NEED TO CREATE A DATABASE IN DESTINATION WITH THE SAME SOURCE NAME OF THE BACKUP DATABASE  FILE NAME THEN LET DESTINATION DATABASE U CREATED GO OFFLINE AND REPLACE IT WITH THE OLD BACKUP DATABASE FILE. AFTER U HAVE DONE IT BRING DESTINATION DATABASE ONLINE. I HOPE IT HELP

Comment: Seems, that your `shift`-key is broken.

Comment: @AFIS - I fixed your other post. But in future, please do not use all capital letters. It diminishes the readability of your response.

Comment: Thanks, however, I can't create database on the destination server